# Why aren't multivariate analyses more popular within econometrics?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, econometrics

I'm currently working on a project that would benefit from having multiple dependent variables. The main model we want to use is a fixed-effects model. My instinct was that it is not okay to repeat the regressions for multiple dependent variables, since we never talked about this in my undergraduate or Master's econometrics courses. Is my instinct correct, or am I wrong? What are the issues with multivariate analysis that make it seemingly unpopular in econometric courses and the literature?

Comment: There are many papers that do this, especially in settings with rich data. The main issue is that if you look at sufficiently many outcomes, you will find a significant effect, so you have have to adjust your inference for "multiple comparisons" when you do this. In some subfields there may not be enough outcomes to test (we only have one GDP in macro).

Comment: Thanks! When you say "adjust your inference for multiple comparisons" are you referring to things like MANOVAs? I'm not very familiar with multivariate analyses.

Comment: I have things like Bonferroni or the Benjamini-Hochberg procedures in mind.

Comment: Ok I will look into this, thanks!